# How to pass NSobject class data from one class to another class in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I am new for ios and in my app I have created one NSModel Object for displaying tableList and when I tap on tableList row I want to take that  model class object data to another class.

How can I do this?

### Viewcontroller:-

```
NSMutableArray * mainArray;

//TableList Delegate Methods:-

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return mainArray.count;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = model1.Name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = model1.MasterId;

    newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,5,30,30)];
    [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(urSelctor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    [newBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:newBtn];

    return cell;
}


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ViewController1 *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    //ModelObject1 *model = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    controller.modelobj = model1;
    controller.modelobjArray = mainArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

-(void)urSelctor :(UIButton*)sender{

    UIImage *currentImage = sender.imageView.image;
    isValidate = [currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]]?NO:YES;
    NSLog(@"VALUE IS : %@", (isValidate) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:((isValidate) ? @"uncheck.png" : @"check.png")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if (isValidate) {
        model1.ischeck = YES;
    }else{
        model1.ischeck = NO;
    }
 }

@end
```

### Modelobject1:-

```
#import "ModelObject1.h"

@implementation ModelObject1

@synthesize MasterId,Name,ischeck;

-(void)loadingservices :(id)mainDictionary{

    NSLog(@"loadingservices %@",mainDictionary);

    Name = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
    MasterId = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"MasterId"];
}

@end
```

### Viewcontroller1:-

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

    @interface ViewController1 ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController1
    @synthesize modelobj,modelobjArray;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        for (int i=0; i<modelobjArray.count;++i) {

            modelobj = modelobjArray[i];
            NSLog(@"Name is=======>%@",modelobj.Name);
            NSLog(@"Check value is%hhd",modelobj.ischeck);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hi, you can prefer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: no no my question is diff compared to this

Comment: The way you wrote the question really looks like what @Son Le has provided. Did you look at this section of that link,  'Passing Data Forward using Segues' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `property` of your `model class` into destination view controller and in source controller, create the object of destination controller and set the value of the model property.

Modify your method like this:

```
-(void)urSelctor :(UIButton*)sender{
    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    if (model1.ischeck) 
    {
        model1.ischeck = NO;
     [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        model1.ischeck = YES;
       [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi can u explain me with some code in my above code
i have added check box on all rows

only that check information not going correctly

Comment: how can i solve this explain with some code please i am very new for ios

Comment: check information means you are getting check mark at wrong place?

Comment: here when i check some check boxes in viewcontroller tableList and when i goes to Viewcontroller1 i want to show there which are checkd and which are unchecked,This is my main intection

Comment: As you have added one key "ischeck" in your model calss, just update the value of that key based on your selection of table row. After that pass that model to another controller.

Comment: model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row]; added this line.

Comment: Welcome brother :-)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this

in your destination view Controller  .h file create property like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "YourObjectClass.h"

@interface DestinationView : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) YourObjectClass           *objectValue;




@end
```

and when you need to pass then

```
 DestinationView *newObjc = // Create object of class
```

and  after that

```
  newObjc.objectValue = yourObjectValue;
```

hope it helps

Comment: above code i have added check box on all rows only that check information not going correctly

Comment: here when i check some check boxes in viewcontroller tableList and when i goes to Viewcontroller1 i want to show there which are checkd and which are unchecked,This is my main intection

Answer (score 0):

Try this,May be this is helpful to you..:)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        ViewController1 *fController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
        model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
        fController.modelVal = model1;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Controller animated:YES];
    }
```

In next view controller:

declare the property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)modelName *modelVal;
```

In  `.m` file

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSLog(@"%@",modelVal.Name);
```

For handling the button use this:

```
-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender {
    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];

if([checkbox1 isSelected]==YES) {
    [checkbox1 setSelected:NO];
} else {
    [checkbox1 setSelected:YES];
}
```

Comment: above code i have added check box on all rows only that check information not going correctly

Comment: here when i check some check boxes in viewcontroller tableList and when i goes to Viewcontroller1 i want to show there which are checkd and which are unchecked,This is my main intection

Comment: did you check   NSLog(@"%@", model1.Name); ..?

Comment: name is going perfectly but check box is checked or not checked not going perfectly

Comment: if name is going perfectly then whats the issue now.?... just update the value of 'ischeck' key on your selection of table row.